# ITextSharp add three points to end of word

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a table with sensors data. There are sensors with long names that do not fit into a cell. 
I want to add three points to end of the long sensor names (like text-overflow: ellipsis in css). I want to do it flexible without hardcoded values. Because in the future number of columns may be different. 
How can I do it?

I create table like this:

```
var table = new PdfPTable(columns.Length);
        var widths = new List<float>();
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            widths.Add(1f);
        }

        table.SetWidths(widths.ToArray());
```

And fill it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(columns[i], tableDataFont));
            cell.UseAscender = true;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(204, 204, 204);
            cell.MinimumHeight = 20f;
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
```

[image: Sensor with long name]

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate proposed by @OwenPauling because it misses the context of iText.

Comment: BTW, reading your question, are you aware that you need to license iTextSharp unless you build something that will be released as open source, and that it costs quite a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
    var text = "testtesttesttesttest";
    var maxLength = 7;
    var displayname = text;

    if (text.Length > maxLength)
    {
        displayname = text.Substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
    }
```

Considering you didn't post any code of your own, I can only provide some logic.

What I do here is just take the real value (insert that into text).

Declare a maximum length you want the text in your fields to be (maxLength).

Create a storage variable to for manipulation of the name without losing the original data (in case you want to keep that).

Then check if the text is longer than the maximumlength and replace all that is too long with "...".

You can then return "displayname" to whatever field you want it to be in.

This most likely isn't what you're looking for, but it does answer your question as it is right now.

Comment: He said that he is using iTextSharp. While it would be better if he provided the code, iTextSharp pretty much defines how the text is handled and your answer misses that context. Downvoted, sorry.

Comment: Thank for your advices) 
I added code of creation of my table and added more accurate description about what I want

Comment: @IvanIčin my bad, I assumed iTextSharp just was an interface he was using. (should've known better, considering the lowercase i.

Comment: @IvanIčin even so, it still would be viable to wrap my code in a method and apply that method to the field that fills in that cell. (unless I'm misunderstanding what iTextSharp is/does.